# Rails Net::SCP file transfer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scp

I have a rake task set up to fetch a folder from a remote server using the `nets/scp` gem. 
My gemfile:

```
gem "net-ssh"
gem "net-scp"
```

My code:

```
require 'net/scp'
desc "Fetch hadoop data"
task :fetch_data => :environment do
 Net::SCP.download!("server_name", "user",
  "/home/dashboard/data", "#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks",
  :password => "password1")
end
```

I get the error:`SCP did not finish successfully (1)`

How do I save the folder to my rails tasks directory, and how can I print out more informaiton about what is causing scp to error? Also, I have my id_rsa key saved in my know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using a different method to scp the file over:

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/scp'

  desc "Fetch hadoop data"
  task :fetch_data => :environment do
    date_yesterday = (DateTime.now - 1.days).strftime("%Y%m%d")
    date_today = (DateTime.now).strftime("%Y%m%d")
    Net::SSH.start("server_name", "user",:password => "*****") do |session|
      session.scp.download!("path_to_file_on_remote", "/home/rails_app/lib/tasks/folder",  :recursive => true)
    end
  end
```